# Glassfish embedded JNDI module scope lookup

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am trying to write JUnit tests by using an embedded glassfish server and EJB3.

I am using maven and my project has 3 modules, and in each of them I want to perform tests.

The module I am currently trying to write tests for is called Backend.

The problem is, that I require a "java:module/" scope for my jndi lookups in the test environment, but when I execute the test only "java:global/classes/" seems to exists.

Does anyone know how I can also execute module scope lookups in an embedded glassfish server?

Some further infos:

- Modul structure:

  - EJB Module (called Backend)
  - WAR Module (called Frontend)
  - JAR Module (utility things)
- POM test dependencies:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this by using Arquillian and deploying my EAR archive as an EnterpriseArchive.